# Checkout problem with PayFast and Magento 2.2

Tags: exception, checkout-page

When I try to make a payment on my site with PayFast, It lets me fill in all details and when you click on "Pay with PayFast" it gives this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'body': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 731


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'body': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 731

#0 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/var/www/suresl...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(125): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load()
#9 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#10 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#11 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(207): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#12 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(241): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild()
#13 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#14 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#15 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#16 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#17 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#18 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#19 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#20 /var/www/sureslim.shop/htdocs/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#21 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your error log, you have an issue in one of your layout files.

You should check all layout files. May **One of layout xml file of your module has only  whitespace between body** tag `<body></body>`. In this case, you should remove those layout files.

Comment: Is there a way for me to know where to look for these files?